# “哩勒公蝦毀” what does this mean?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, topolect, taiwanese

What does “哩勒公蝦毀” mean? A Taiwanese guy said that to me after I had, accidently, mistyped two words in an idiom I used on him.

He also used an expression of surprise (I presume) which went like “蛤？！” (after I said he seemed like a guy whom a conversation would get easily boring with) What does that mean too?

Comment: Apparently, that the guy said "huh? Could you speak up?" (after it had already been brought up that he would be someone who things would get easily boring with) indicates he was a bit of a clod.

Answer (score 12):

**哩勒公蝦毀**

This sentence refers to the pronunciation of "What did you say?" in [Min-Nan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min_Nan)

- 哩(ㄌㄧ): You
- 勒(ㄌㄟ): an auxiliary verb
- 公(ㄍㄨㄥ): say
- 蝦毀(ㄒㄧㄚ ㄏㄨㄟˇ): what

**蛤？！**

This word equals to ["Huh? Could you speak up?"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/huh#English). Taiwanese use this word commonly on the Internet because it's the first word choice in Bopomofo input method of "ㄏㄚˊ"

[image]

Comment: lol, so it's english written in chinese. 爱老虎油 = i love u

Comment: How the f*ck did that guy expect me to understand that?! So, how does “li lei gong xia hui” come close in pronunciation to “你剛說了什麼？”？

Comment: @user76935, it's not putonghua, it's min-nan

Comment: 吳伯等min-nan or bop-mof. He must have had a sudden brain stroke or something that he thought I was Taiwanese...(*offensive! -_-)

Comment: @Peter Chung - Could you add or explain in your answer how 哩勒公蝦毀 is actually “what did you say?” in Min-Nan? Then I'll give you +1.

Comment: @user76935 added

Comment: @Peter Chung - Voted up :)

Answer (score 7):

This is a Taiwanese (Min-nan) utterance.

pronunciation:
“哩(li) 勒(le) 公(gong) 蝦毀(siann-hue)?”

translation word by word: 
You    are    saying   what-thing?

There is a hot Disney movie song FROZEN - Let It Go.
Recently, we have a Taiwanese version of it

### http://youtu.be/23F1iAq__P8

at time slot during 1:18~1:21

There is a similar sentence (only the subject is different. you --> they)

subtile:

"他們 (Yin) 到底 (dau-de) 在(le) 講(gong) 啥貨(siann-hue)?"

translation in English word by word:

"They on earth are saying what-thing?"

I cut that short segment here for easy reference

### http://youtu.be/TZmCtU6uzN8

[image: 他們到底在講啥貨]

By the way, I have to point out that 
because of lack of standardization of written form for Taiwanese,
there will be different ways for writing the same utterance.
e.g.

哩(li) 勒(le) 公(gong) 蝦毀(siann-hue)?

v.s.

你(li) 在(le) 講(gong) 啥貨(siann-hue)?

The latter is better because those Chinese characters have real meaning to represent those sound.

The former one just use the homonyms, those characters are meaningless in this case, even Chinese native speakers cannot understand the former sentence.

So, frankly speaking, the topic sentence in this question is actually not a correct sentence or not a good sentence to represent a commonly used Taiwanese daily sentence!!

Comment: Sentences or questions don't need to represent all the commonly-spoken Chinese only. It's about all of the Chinese language and rare examples are still Chinese language.

Answer (score 6):

The meaning of "哩勒公蝦毀" (li lei gong xia hui) is "What are you talking about?". And "蛤？！" means "What?".

In one orthography of Taiwanese, the phrase "哩勒公蝦毀" could be written as "汝咧講啥貨" (ru lie jiang sha huo), which literally means "What things are you talking about?" Its Roman transcription would be "lí leh kóng siáⁿ-hòe" (in [POJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pe%CC%8Dh-%C5%8De-j%C4%AB) style).

Since most Taiwanese people didn't learn the proper writing standards of Taiwanese at school, they just started using these characters arbitrarily, according to Mandarin homophones.

"蛤" is also just selected by the Taiwanese, based on Mandarin homophones. The pronunciation of this character is "hã" (or "hâⁿ" in POJ), of which "ã" means a nasal vowel. Moreover, there is no consensus on the character usage of this term.

Answer (score 4):

The phrase means "What did you say?"

Comment: Asking a question doesn't provide an answer to the OP's question. Leave any remarks and questions directly underneath the question in the comments section

Comment: It is an answer. Just not so sure but I am 99% sure. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Asking a question on a question is not considered an answer. Read the "help" guidelines on how to, properly, formulate an answer if you still don't understand that.

Comment: This is an answer period. Fornalism is beuracracy and superficial.

Comment: I suggest you read the help guidelines. You know, there is an actual place where you can criticize others or express your disagreement about anything. It's not here, in the answer section, though.

Comment: It's a lemma to the answer which happens to be the answer. Also This question contains non-standard use of Chinese characters. It might be misleading to foreigners. It would be better if you post it somewhere else or just google it. If you pick more fight, I will ignore.

Comment: I don't care if you're going to ignore me, delete your account or whatever. This is a future reference for those who do want to positively contribute to this website: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

It means "What the hell are you talking about?"

Sometimes will use"哩勒公蝦小" It will more impolite. Because 蝦小 can means WTF